# Minimizer of the functional involving infinitely many variables.

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Consider the functional $$\min f= \min \bigg(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2^{-n}x_n-2^{-\frac{3n}{2}})^2+\lambda \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n^2\bigg)$$ where $x_1, x_2, \cdots $ are infinite real variables and $\lambda$ is Lagrange multiplier.
How to find minimizer of the above functional?

My Idea:I know that the function $f$ has a unique minimizer because it is strictly convex, bounded below. From theory, I know the first order necessary criteria according to which $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}=0\ \forall n.$$
Is this criteria sufficient also? Please help.

Comment: In this case the variables are "decupled", and your procedure will work. and the resulting $f$ value will be finite.  More generally, however, things become more complicated...

Comment: Sir, decupled means what here?

Comment: I don't think there is a formal definition of the term.  I just meant that your objective function is the sum of a function of $x_1$ alone plus a function of $x_2$ alone, and so on, so your choice for $x_1$ does not influence your choice for $x_2$, etc.

Comment: Ok. Any hint how to say it concretely sir?

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the stationary points

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n} = 2\cdot 2^{-n}(2^{-n}x_n-2^{-\frac{3n}{2}})+2\lambda x_n = 0
$$

we have

$$
x_n^* = \frac{2^{-\frac{5n}{2}}}{2^{-2n}+\lambda}
$$

then $x_n^*$ should obey the restriction

$$
\sum_{n}^{\infty}(x_n^*)^2 = \sum_{n}^{\infty}\frac{2^{-5n}}{(2^{-2n}+\lambda)^2}=0\Rightarrow \lambda \to\infty
$$

This is possible only if $x_n^* = 0\forall n$ so the minimum is

$$
\min f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-3n}= \frac 17
$$

Comment: I don't understand this restriction sir. Can you please explain it?

Comment: The lagrange multiplier $\lambda$  is associated with a restriction that I assumed to be
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k^2 = 0$. In the lagangian we have $\lambda \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x_k^2 = 0$