# Infinite dimensional optimization

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Is it possible to deduce the minimum of a real functional involving countably infinitely many variables given that its partial derivative exist with respect to each variable, and it has a unique minimizer?

Can we obtain its minimum by putting partial derivatives zero?

Comment: It is sometimes possible, but it is not possible in general.  Do you have a specific problem in mind?

Comment: Please look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510897/minimizer-of-the-functional-involving-infinitely-many-variables